# libtool did not generate a lo file when everything is there

Tags: makefile, libtool

I'm new to using libtool. However, this problem seems to be weird. Everything is there but the libtool said "libtool: link: 'cuda_transfer.lo' is not a valid libtool object". However, the rule for generating this lo file is right there in the Makefile. Besides, the two header files are also right in where they are supposed to be and do work. Any idea about what is going wrong?

```
cuda_transfer.lo: particles_cuda.h ../../include/psc_particles_cuda.h
```

The other two places in Makefile where cuda_transfer.lo appeared are followed

```
libsubdir_la_DEPENDENCIES = cuda_transfer.lo \

libsubdir_la_LIBADD = \
    cuda_transfer.lo \
```

The .c.lo: segment is following:

```
.c.lo:
    $(AM_V_CC)depbase=`echo $@ | sed 's|[^/]*$$|$(DEPDIR)/&|;s|\.lo$$||'`;\
    $(LTCOMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $$depbase.Tpo -c -o $@ $< &&\
    $(am__mv) $$depbase.Tpo $$depbase.Plo
#   $(AM_V_CC)source='$<' object='$@' libtool=yes \
#   DEPDIR=$(DEPDIR) $(CCDEPMODE) $(depcomp) \
#   $(AM_V_CC_no)$(LTCOMPILE) -c -o $@ $<
```

How to interpret this human-unfriendly code. = =

Below is the code segment suggested by Brett.

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libsubdir.la
libsubdir_la_SOURCES = \
        psc_fields_cuda.c \
        psc_particles_cuda.c \
        psc_push_particles_cuda.c \
        psc_push_fields_cuda.c \
        psc_bnd_cuda.c \
        psc_bnd_particles_cuda.c \
        psc_bnd_fields_cuda.c \
        b40c/kernel_utils.h \
        b40c/radixsort_kernel_common.h \
        b40c/radixsort_key_conversion.h \
        b40c/radixsort_reduction_kernel.h \
        b40c/radixsort_scanscatter_kernel.h \
        b40c/radixsort_scanscatter_kernel3.h \
        b40c/radixsort_scanscatter_kernel4.h \
        b40c/radixsort_spine_kernel.h \
        b40c/vector_types.h \
        cuda_common.h \
        cuda_sort2.h \
        cuda_sort2_spine.h \
        particles_cuda.h \
        psc_bnd_cuda.h \
        psc_bnd_cuda_fields.h \
        psc_cuda.h

libsubdir_la_LIBADD = \
        cuda_transfer.lo \
        cuda_spine.lo \
        cuda_sort2.lo \
        cuda_sort3.lo \
        cuda_exchange_particles.lo \
        cuda_exclusive_scan_2.lo \
        cuda_push_part_yz_1vb.lo
```

The only thing that looks like a generating rule about cuda_transfer.lo is

```
cuda_transfer.lo: particles_cuda.h ../../include/psc_particles_cuda.h
```

Comment: Did you have, say, `lib_LTLIBRARIES = libsubdir.la` followed by `libsubdir_la_SOURCES = cuda_transfer.c` ?

Comment: I added that segment to my problem description as you can see above. The rule to generate cuda_transfer.lo is also inserted.

Comment: So how exactly did you (prebuild) the libtool objects in `LIBADD`? These will *not* be generated as it is now. They are expected to exist as proper libtool objects, or by listing their sources in: `EXTRA_libsubdir_la_SOURCES`.

Comment: I see. So actually `libsubdir_la_DEPENDENCIES = cuda_transfer.lo ` has reminded me about this fact at first? Then how can I build the `cuda_transfer.lo`? The only thing that looks like a generating rule about `cude_transfer.lo` is `cuda_transfer.lo: particles_cuda.h ../../include/psc_particles_cuda.h` in the Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's better not to read `configure.ac` ever :-) But if you still wish, `configure.ac` is a combination of `m4` preprocessor code and ordinary (bourne) shell snippets. You may check `info m4` and `info autoconf`, the docs are pretty decent.

The hard part of your question, regarding the `.lo` file. It seems that your makefile contains dependency chain for it, but no explicit build-rules. You may try to locate a common rule for compiling `.c` -> `.lo`, like this:

```
.c.lo:
      $(AM_V_CC)$(LTCOMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo -c -o $@ $<
      $(AM_V_at)$(am__mv) $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo $(DEPDIR)/$*.Plo
      ...
```

Comment: You are awesome! There is indeed something like it. I added it to my question above. However, I don't think it is human-friendly... How to interpret it...

Comment: Well this is the line to invoke the compiler via a libtool-specific wrapper. It produces .lo-files (libtool objects) from their .c-counterparts, http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules. Certainly it looks a bit horrible but afterall Automake-generated Makefiles aren't what one wish to inspect on everyday basis :).

Comment: What you need to do at this point is to debug dependencies/rules chain of the Makefile. Try issue `make -d  cuda_transfer.lo >build.log`. All lines prior to ` No need to remake target `Makefile'.` can be safely ignored/deleted.

Answer (score 3):

try this：

```
yum -y install libtool*
```

then make clean and restart again

Answer (score 1):

Install latest libtool. Delete the .lo file and use 'make' again.